# how to Load data from database into separate pictureBox

Tags: c#

I have two pictureBox; pictureBox1 and pictureBox2,

In my database i have PicID and Picture, and two pictures in it

I want to load the pictures, but the first picture should be in pictureBox1 and the second picture should be in pictureBox2.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried ?

Comment: Are `PicID` and `Picture` picture files

Comment: PicID is the primary Key(identification Numbers), and Picture contains the Picture files                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                          
i have two pictureBox, i want a code which can help me load, the first Picture file into PictureBox1 and the second Picture file into PictureBox2 from my database StudentPic